# How to host Microservices

Tags: azure, docker, nginx, azure-container-service

I'm totally new to Azure and overwhelmed by all the azure services.
I have simple use-case and want to know what is the best (and cheapest option) to host this in Azure (it must be on azure).

Important: All Docker images are windows-based!

There is an Web Assembly / Webpage, build in a Docker image.
There are two Services. Maybe more in the future. Each service in a separate Docker image.
The hosting of the services should be scalable. But not high-scalable. It's enough if it can be scaled with a redeploy at night time.
There is also an NGINX Docker image for load balancing, routing and certificate handling.

The Web Assembly should have a Public IP Address.
The services should be private and not accessible from the internet.

So, how should I deploy this in azure?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I am relatively new to azure as well, but sounds like Azure App Service is a fit. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/intro/hosting-apps-on-azure) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/deploy-run-container-app-service/)

Comment: Two options are there
`First option-` Azure Container Instances is a great option if you're looking for simplicity and don't require the full orchestration capabilities of Kubernetes. Deploy the Docker image as a container in ACI with a public IP address. For load balancing and routing, consider using Azure's native services like Azure Front Door or Azure Application Gateway instead of running your own NGINX container.

Comment: `Second option-` Use AKS. Deploy your services, Web Assembly/Webpage, and potentially even NGINX (if opting to manage it yourself) within an AKS cluster. Use Kubernetes deployments and services to manage your containers. Expose the Web Assembly/Webpage through a Kubernetes service of type LoadBalancer, which provides a public IP. But yes, AKS has potentially higher cost due to cluster and node management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you have different options.
Option 1- Using [AKS](https://openliberty.io/guides/cloud-azure.html#creating-a-deployment-definition)
Option 2- like [Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/deploy-run-container-app-service/) as [Veverke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1219280/veverke) mentioned.

How to choose the best option?

- If simplicity and cost are your primary concerns, start with Azure Container Instances or Azure Container App Service and Azure Application Gateway or Front Door.
- For applications that might grow in complexity, requiring detailed orchestration, scaling, and management, then Azure Kubernetes Service is the more suitable option.

Since you have Windows-based Docker images, you can use AKS with Windows Server containers. You can deploy your Web Assembly/Webpage and services as separate deployments in AKS, and use an NGINX ingress controller to handle load balancing, routing, and certificate handling. You can also use Kubernetes secrets to keep your services private and not accessible from the internet.

Similar example to demonstrate # [How to host Microservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78072890/how-to-host-microservices) on AKS

Login to azure using `az login`
Create an ACR and connect to it

```
az acr create -g rgname -n [registry-name] --sku Basic --admin-enabled

az acr login -n [registry-name]
```

[image]

build your docker image

```
mvn package
```

[image]
[image]

```
docker build -t system:1.0-SNAPSHOT system/.
docker build -t inventory:1.0-SNAPSHOT inventory/.
```

[image]
[image]

Check your image using-

```
  docker images
```

[image]

Tag and Push the image into your acr which you created above

```
docker tag system:1.0-SNAPSHOT [registry-server]/system:1.0-SNAPSHOT
docker tag inventory:1.0-SNAPSHOT [registry-server]/inventory:1.0-SNAPSHOT

docker push [registry-server]/system:1.0-SNAPSHOT
docker push [registry-server]/inventory:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

[image]

Create your aks cluster

```
az aks create -g rgname -n guideCluster
```

[image]

Once cluster is up, verify using `kubectl get nodes`
[image]

Create your deployments and services accordingly.
[image]

in my case-

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: system-deployment
  labels:
    app: system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: system
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: system
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: system-container
        image: arkoacr.azurecr.io/system:1.0-SNAPSHOT
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9080
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: guidesecret
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: inventory-deployment
  labels:
    app: inventory
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: inventory
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: inventory
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: inventory-container
        image: arkoacr.azurecr.io/inventory:1.0-SNAPSHOT
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9081
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: guidesecret
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: system-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: system
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 9080
    targetPort: 9080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: inventory-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: inventory
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 9081
    targetPort: 9081
```

apply it using `kubectl apply -f <youryamlfilename.yaml>`
and now when you do `kubectl get pods` or `kubectl get service`
[image]
[image]

You see that AKS has successfully deployed your microservice. It also provides automated Kubernetes version upgrades and patching, easy cluster scaling, and a self-healing hosted control plane. It also offers cost savings by only charging for running agent pool nodes. With Azure handling the management of the nodes in your AKS cluster, you no longer need to perform many tasks manually, like cluster upgrades. Because Azure handles these critical maintenance tasks for you.

Comment: thanks in advance for the detailed reply. kubernetes is a little bit to complex and configurable. 
By "Azure Container App Service " you mean "App Services"? Because "Container Apps" are only for Linux afaik.
I will have a look into Front Door and Application Gateway and give it a try

Comment: The solution was a "App Service - Web App", than a injection of a virtual network, and an integratrion in the same vnet. the services were deployed as container instances with private networking in the same vnet.